# Will my DataBase get affected after using Postman?

Tags: postman

I need to test my API by passing a URL to Postman. I didn't tried yet, but I have to.

Can anybody help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Depends** on your API.

If it's set to make `INSERTs`, `UPDATEs` or anything, **it will affect** your DataBase.

Show us that code, than we can tell you.

[Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) just **POST** or **GET** into your URL. What is going to happen after that is on your API hands.

Comment: You're welcome! And @vicky , if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.